# material design selectbox polymer

Tags: polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I noticed there were no "selectbox" widgets within the Paper Elements section of Polymer documentation, nor did I see one in the Polymer GitHub repos.  Also I don't recall seeing any specific guidance on the Material Design specifications as to how a selectbox should look or behave.

Are there proposals out there?  Or specific plans to incorporate designs for selectboxes within material design / polymer paper elements?

I definitely understand that you can basically get the same functionality from checkboxes (multi) or radio buttons (single), but from an aesthetic perspective, depending on the specific application, I get the feeling it may be a good idea to have 'select' available as an option.

Comment: We're looking into providing a select-type material element. Nothing yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the paper-dropdown-menu, for example:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Favorite fruit" name="fruit">
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
      <core-menu class="menu">
        <paper-item>apples</paper-item>
        <paper-item>oranges</paper-item>
        <paper-item>pears</paper-item>
      </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I imagine the next steps will be supporting 'multiple' attribute, but looks like they've resolved this now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of these will fill your needs?

### [core-selector](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector)

```
<core-selector selected="0">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
</core-selector>
```

### [core-dropdown](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-dropdown)

```
<core-dropdown selected="Financier" valueattr="label">
    <core-item label="Croissant"></core-item>
    <core-item label="Donut"></core-item>
    <core-item label="Financier"></core-item>
    <core-item label="Madeleine"></core-item>
</core-dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've definitely gone through existing components to see what's available on the polymer site.  And I've even contemplated creating my own based on the concepts that exist in the paper elements available today.  The original thread was created primarily as a way to figure out what the paper select element will look like, or if it will even exist.  Even if the Polymer project hasn't gotten around to it, I'd be interested to see if there's a spec (or other attempts) that can be followed, or guidance on how they want the select to work within the "paper element" context.